# AWS Athena error: Value cannot be cast to timestamp

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, unix-timestamp

I need to query for records with a timestamp no older than 7 days.

What type do I need to cast the timestamp field to remedy the error? *Or, is there a more succinct / correct way to build the query?*

Query:

```
SELECT report_timestamp
FROM my_table
WHERE to_unixtime(CAST(report_timestamp AS timestamp)) >= to_unixtime(CAST(now() - interval '7' day AS timestamp))
```

Error:

```
Value cannot be cast to timestamp: 1659612600
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `CAST(report_timestamp AS timestamp)` to `from_unixtime`:

```sql
select from_unixtime(1659612600);
```

Or to `from_unixtime(cast(report_timestamp as integer))` (since you mentioned in the comments that `report_timestamp` is varchar):

```sql
select from_unixtime(cast('1659612600' as integer));
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-08-04 11:30:00.000 UTC |

Comment: Thank you. I changed my WHERE clause to 'WHERE from_unixtime(cast(report_timestamp as integer)) >= date_add('day', -7, now())' and that resolved the error, however, the query doesn't return any results and there report_timestamp values that are >= the current date.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman `1659612600` value was taken from your error message and it corresponds to `2022-08-04 11:30:00.000 UTC` which is definitely not >= current date. Even more - it more than 7 days from now.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That date was returned by the error because it was a value checked by the query but, there are many other dates that should be returned that meet the criteria of being within the last 7 days.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman without access to the data and knowledge of it's meaning and structure it is hard to say.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. The report_timestamp field is unix timstamps, example, 1659648600. I want to select that table and only return records that are no older than 7 days.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman `1659648600` is  `2022-08-04 21:30:00.000 UTC` which also is outside of 7 day period.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made a conversion mistake on my end, thank you for your patience. I got it working. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT report_timestamp
FROM my_table
WHERE from_unixtime(CAST(report_timestamp AS bigint)) >= date_add('day', -7, now());
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, Athena returns the same error.

Comment: Okay, then the problem lies within report_timestamp. Could you provide a sample value?

Comment: And what data type is report_timestamp?

Comment: report_timestamp is type string, example "1659612600".

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work now.

Comment: Thank you. Your most recent edit returns: mismatched input 'as'. Expecting: ',', <expression>

Comment: Fixed the problem

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your last edit worked. I accepted the other answer because it was posted first and also works. Cheers.